# Kotlin: parsing a list of pairs delimited by parentheses into a list of Pairs()

Tags: kotlin, parsing, split, coordinates, edges

I haven't figured out how to use the Kotlin `split` function to parse this series of edges into a `List` of `Pairs`.

```
(2, 4), (3, 6), (5, 1), (8, 9), (10, 12), (11, 7)
```

I could write a character by character parser with no problem - but it there a Kotlin solution to this parsing problem?

Comment: Is the format of the data guaranteed to be like this or you need to verify it while parsing?

Comment: The format is guaranteed - this is a problem for a Bioinformatics course and not "data in the wild".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aleksei's answer should work fine, although it doesn't give you numbers.

Also, I'd rather write it this way (broken down into functions):

```kotlin
private fun String.parsePairs(): List<Pair<Int, Int>> = removePrefix("(")
    .removeSuffix(")")
    .split("), (")
    .map { it.parsePair() }

private fun String.parsePair(): Pair<Int, Int> =
    split(", ").let { it[0].toInt() to it[1].toInt() }
```

Another option is to use regex. It's a bit overkill here, but more general in case you have more complex requirements:

```kotlin
val regex = Regex("""\((\d+),\s*(\d+)\)""")

private fun String.parsePairs(): List<Pair<Int, Int>> = regex.findAll(this)
        .map { it.groupValues[1].toInt() to it.groupValues[2].toInt() }
        .toList()
```

Comment: I like the first solution in this reply the most as it is very readable and returns the list of Pair<Int, Int> in the result.  Sorry that I wasn't specific on this in the question.  Plus I learned about removePrefix() and removeSuffix(), that is great!

Comment: @JimAndreas Thanks, glad to help. Note that these chained steps are nice and readable but generate a bunch of intermediate objects that you wouldn't have if you read the string character by character. If this is in a really hot path, it might be worth going "manual" but otherwise it's cool to keep it tidy.

Answer (score 2):

```
s.substring(1, s.length-1)
    .split("), (")
    .map { it.split(", ") }
    .map { it[0] to it[1] }
```